# My pages do not appear after authentication in Angular 12

Tags: angular

My pages does not appear after an authentification in Angular 12

I am completely lost in my paths (parent and child)

1. I enter the identifications (pseudo -> toto and password -> 1234)

[img - login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbTkQ.png)

2. I am redirected to the `Portfolio` page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LlRT.png)

For now, I don't have any problem

3. When I click on `Account Opening`, the Account Opening doesn't work !

[img - Account Opening doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfY3d.png)

The schema is presented like this

[img - Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEj3c.png)

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivateTeam } from '../../core/canActivateTeam.guard';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const DASHBOARD_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateTeam],

    children: [
      {
        path: 'administration',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./views/administration/administration.module').then(
            (m) => m.AdministrationModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'market',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./views/market/market.module').then((m) => m.MarketModule),
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(DASHBOARD_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

**administration-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../../dashboard.component';

import { AdministrationComponent } from './administration.component';

import { AccountOpeningComponent } from './views/account-opening/account-opening.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './views/portfolio/portfolio.component';



export const ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,

    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'portfolio',
      },
      {
        path: 'portfolio',
        component: PortfolioComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'account-opening',
        component: AccountOpeningComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AdministrationRoutingModule {}
```

I don't know how to solve this, I have tried almost everything.

The code is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gw6h9f-jbhfmg?file=src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts).

I'm sure these are the paths but I'm completely lost...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to be more explicit  [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gw6h9f-zvvqkv?file=src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts)

```
submenus: [
        {
          class: 'bx bx-key',
          item: 'Account Opening',
          route: '/dashboard/administration/account-opening',
        },
        {
          class: 'bx bx-wallet',
          item: 'Portfolio',
          route: '/dashboard/administration/portfolio',
        },
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dashboard.component.ts` you can:

- For Expanding menu items, you don't want them to have routes since their components only holds the `router-outlet` and I assume you also you don't want to navigate anywhere yet.

```
      class: 'bx bx-lock-alt',
      item: 'Administration',
      route: '/dashboard/adiministration', // <- Remove this line
      arrowDown: 'bx bx-chevron-down',
      arrowUp: 'bx bx-chevron-up',
```

You can do the same for the `Market` menu item

- For the market submenus you need to explicitly specify the route as there are grandchildren of dashboard

```
      {
         class: 'bx bx-coin-stack',
         item: 'Value',
         route: '/market/value', // <- /dashboard/market/value
       },
       {
         class: 'bx bx-line-chart',
         item: 'Indice',
         route: '/market/indice',  // <- /dashboard/market/indice
       },
```